# including js through module info file is not working

Tags: 7

mymodule.info:

```
name = custom
description = custom module

core = 7.x
version 7.x-0.1

scripts[] = custom.js
```

created the file custom.js in the same folder as custom.module file
I have the `$scripts` variable in html.tpl.php
cleared all caches

Still cannot see custom.js in page sources. What else it might be?

Comment: Your custom module is activated? Nothing shown in javascript console (with Firebug or Developer Toolbar)? Any watchdog errors?

Comment: Yes, it's activated. But there's no errors in console. Same with watchdog. Is it working at all? (i mean js file in info a module info file)

Comment: Yes it should work as stated here: https://drupal.org/node/542202#scripts. Maybe check file permissions and try to put a simple "drupal_set_message" into your module to check if it is well installed.

Comment: if i do drupal_add_js() inside my .module file it works, it's not working if i use it in info file.

Comment: Try removing the "version 7.x-0.1" line, as it is discouraged (https://drupal.org/node/542202#version) and it is not the right syntax (should be `version = "7.x-0.1"`)

Comment: lol i forgot "=" sign: version 7.x-0.1
Thanks

Comment: Did that fix your issue? If yes, i'll post the comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: let me check 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with a typo in the info file. It's missing a "=" on the version line.
Correct info file here:

```
name = custom
description = custom module

core = 7.x
version = 7.x-0.1

scripts[] = custom.js
```

Also note that the version properties is [discouraged](https://drupal.org/node/542202#version)

Comment: Version is only discouraged if your module is to be hosted on Drupal.org. If you've written a local module for a custom project/client -- then *of course* you want a version number.